# Learn error with wget command using PowerShell & Batch File

Tags: powershell, batch-file, wget

I have a power shell script that invokes a .cmd file. Here the architecture looks like

-PowerShell File Code

$arguments='/savecred /profile /user:myDomain\myuser "cmd /c C:\Users\myuser\code.cmd"'
Start-Process cmd.exe $arguments -Wait

- .cmd code file

Here the code invokes wget request to download a file

wget .....(command here)

My goal is to learn at PowerShell command prompt (after completing Start-Process command) whether the wget command executed successfully or some error like 401, 404 occurred during the execution. Here I am particular not interested in the type of error, just need to know whether error occurred or not.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are asking but you could test none-zero return code of the last command using $? variable, which will be $false if return code is not zero.

Let's say you have a test.cmd file which simply returns 5:

```
exit 5
```

If you run it within PowerShell, you can look at the result of $?

```
if ($?) {"No error"} else {"some error"}
```

Here is a link for more info: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/12/powershell-error-handling-and-why-you-should-care.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using `$?` with Start-Process isn't going to work:

```
C:\PS> Start-Process cmd.exe -arg '/c exit 5'
C:\PS> $?
True
```

If you want to use Start-Process, you can go this route:

```
C:\PS> $p = Start-Process cmd.exe -arg '/c exit 5' -PassThru -Wait
C:\PS> $p.ExitCode
5
```

Or you could just invoke cmd.exe directly:

```
C:\PS> cmd /c exit 5
C:\PS> $LASTEXITCODE
5
```

In this last example you could use `$?` but I prefer `$LastExitCode` since some brain-damaged console apps return non-zero for success.  Regarding calling cmd.exe and using $LASTEXITCODE see this [ScriptingGuy blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/10/01/powertip-launch-cmd-exe-commands-from-powershell.aspx).

For a handy `CheckLastExitCode` function look through [this blog post](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2009/08/03/effective-powershell-item-16-dealing-with-errors/) for an implementation of the function.

Comment: Yes, that's true for start-process but both $? and $lastexitcode works with cmd /c exit 5

Comment: I am trying to use $? and it returns true, even though my wget command in the code.cmd file fails.
Is there a way to return non-zero exitcode to PowerShell, if wget command fails.

Comment: @VarunGupta Yes there is. If you want to continue to use Start-Procss, use the middle example above that captures the process object in $p and then uses its ExitCode `property`.  If you eliminate the Start-Process and call cmd.exe directly, use the last example above which uses $LastExitCode.

Comment: @AdilH. Whether or not that "works" depends on your semantics for a return value of 5.  If that is meant to indicate failure i.e. $? should be false then yeah it works. However I've seen EXEs where 5 would be a success value so $? returning false would not work.